# How to get actual position of qtoolbar?

Tags: qt

I am just trying to get the actual x, y values or  `Qt::ToolBarArea` area of my `QToolBar`.

Is there any function to get it so?

Comment: What are you trying to get the position relative to?

Comment: Any QWidget has a set of methods you can use to get coordinates relative to parent widgets or global widgets: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapTo (See mapTo, mapToGlobal and mapToParent) Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I will get te last position of my QToolBar and then I l save this value in a string to use it aftr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`QWidget::mapTo`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapTo) and associated functions. I reckon you want to do something like:

`yourWidget->mapToParent(0, 0)` - maps the top left corner of `yourWidget` (i.e. `0, 0`) to the coordinate system of its parent widget.